# How to stop iterating after top 10 in sort_by

Tags: ruby, sorting, iteration

Can't figure out how to only print the first 10 lines of this result here. Have tried a while and i +=1 approach, but couldn't fit it in.

```
# make the hash default to 0 so that += will work correctly
from_count = Hash.new(0)

# iterate over the array, counting duplicate entries
results.each do |v|
  from_count[v] += 1
end

#prints all k,v values sorted by v but I only want the first 10 lines
from_count.sort_by { |k, v| v }.reverse.each{|k,v| puts "Top 10: \n\n #{v} -- #{k}"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite simple :)

```
from_count.sort_by { |k, v| v }.reverse.first(10).each{|k,v| puts "Top 10: \n\n #{v} -- #{k}"}
                                          ^
```

Comment: Haha wow. First dive into Ruby I will look back with much embarrassment on these early questions some day. Thanks!

Comment: @krapdagn: surely you will :)

Comment: Sorry - had to let it sit b4 it let me accept. Thank you again!

Comment: is there a way to stop the sort after the top 10 are found? this answer is simply taking the first 10 entries, AFTER the sort is complete.

Comment: @Ben: how do you know that you've found the right 10 elements before you process all of them?

Answer (score 1):

Since Ruby 2.2 you can do

```
from_count.max_by(10){ |k, v| v }
```